# How in kotlin to initialize a two dimensional non-nullable string array

Tags: arrays, kotlin, non-nullable

Having a two demential string array and the row has only two items,

`i.e.  {{"1", "a"} {"2", "b"}, {"3", "c"} ... ...}`

the invert function to do the invert

```
public static String[][] invert(final String[][] array) {
    final String[][] newarray = new String[array.length][2];
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
        newarray[i][0] = array[i][1];
        newarray[i][1] = array[i][0];
    }
    return newarray;
}
```

translate to kotlin:

1. ```
   fun invert(array: Array<Array<String?>>): Array<Array<String?>> {
       val newarray = Array<Array<String?>>(array.size) { arrayOfNulls(2) }
       for (i in array.indices) {
           newarray[i][0] = array[i][1]
           newarray[i][1] = array[i][0]
       }
       return newarray
   }
   ```

Because of the `arrayOfNulls(2)`,  has to define the two demential array to be `Array<Array<String?>>`

but the return type of `Array<Array<String?>>`  breaks the a lot of the code which expecting `Array<Array<String>>`

2. Using the `val newarray = Array<Array<String>>(array.size) { Array<String>(2) {""}}` to force the array initialized all rows with empty string (so not null).

   ```
   fun invert(array: Array<Array<String>>): Array<Array<String>> {
       val newarray = Array<Array<String>>(array.size) { Array<String>(2) {""}}
       for (i in array.indices) {
           newarray[i][0] = array[i][1]
           newarray[i][1] = array[i][0]
       }
       return newarray
   }
   ```

Is it the only way,  or is there some function like

```
fun strinagArrayOf(vararg elements: String): Array<String>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That translation threw you off the track; there's no reason to initialize and loop again through the fields.

This is signature of constructor you're using:

```
/**
 * Creates a new array with the specified [size], where each element is calculated by calling the specified
 * [init] function. The [init] function returns an array element given its index.
 */
public inline constructor(size: Int, init: (Int) -> T)
```

You actually get to pass you own initialization logic for each item in the `init` function. You even get index of item you're initializing (it's the only argument so it's not explicitly declared but it's accesible as `it`).

So to get what you need, You can simply initialize inverted array right there (changed param from `array` to `input` for readability):

```
fun invert(input: Array<Array<String>>) = Array(input.size) {arrayOf(input[it][1], input[it][0]) }
```